# Get unchecked list item value from checkboxlist c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

In below example , checkboxlist list 6 list items  and if I uncheck any item , i should be able to get the unchecked value

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList id="chkbxFileTypes" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkbxFileTypes_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack=true>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

If I uncheck Item1 list item, i need to get the value of the same ?

Which event should i use , as now I use selected index change and it      just gives me selected value and not the unselected value ?

Please help

Comment: Where would you like to handle this, on server or on client?

Comment: server ? I did not use javascript , jus pure asp.net controls

Answer (score 1):

In yourcode behind you can handel the event `chkbxFileTypes_SelectedIndexChanged` like :

```
protected void chkbxFileTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           List<ListItem> selected = chkbxFileTypes.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
          .Where(li => ! li.Selected)
          .ToList();
        }
```

or with a simple foreach:

```
  List<string> selectedValues = chkbxFileTypes.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
         .Where(li => ! li.Selected )
         .Select(li => li.Value)
         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void chkbxFileTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string checkedid = "";
        string uncheckedValue = "";
        foreach (ListItem val in chkbxFileTypes.Items)
        {
            if (val.Selected)
            {
                checkedid += val.Value + " ";
            }
            else
            {
                uncheckedValue += val.Value + ",";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For eg :  there are 4 List Items
A,
B,
C,
D
and  A & B is in checked state ,
if I try to uncheck B then i should be able to get value of B without looping .. Is it possible to ?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void chkbxFileTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string eventTarget = Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(eventTarget.Substring(eventTarget.Length-1));
        bool isUnchecked = !chkbxFileTypes.Items[index].Selected;
        if (isUnchecked)
        {
            string value = chkbxFileTypes.Items[index].Value;
        }
    }
```

Use "__EVENTTARGET" form element to find the index of target checkbox and then check if its unchecked. If its unchecked then get it's value.

Comment: For eg :  there are 4 List Items
A,
B,
C,
D
and  A & B is in checked state ,
if I try to uncheck B then i should be able to get value of B without looping .. Is it possible to ?

Comment: yes it is possible using my code. it is working on my end. can you share the html of checkboxlist

Comment: will try once again , anyways thank you.. will update you

Comment: My checkbox list is inside a repeater .. is it because of that ?

Comment: yeah it can be because of that. can you share the html of checkboxlist

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void chkbxFileTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string checkedValue = "";
    string uncheckedValue = "";
    foreach (ListItem val in chkbxFileTypes.Items)
    {
        if (val.Selected)
        {
            checkedValue += val.Value + " ";
        }
        else
        {
            uncheckedValue += val.Value + ",";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very difficult to read, see this for details on how to format your posts http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: For eg :  there are 4 List Items
A,
B,
C,
D
and  A & B is in checked state ,
if I try to uncheck B then i should be able to get value of B without looping .. Is it possible to ?